# Loop through 3 arrays at once and save values in the database

Tags: php, cakephp

I have three inputs type text in an HTML page and a button which if clicked duplicate each text box (Javascript) making them 6.

```
<input type="text" name="category[]">
<input type="text" name="quantity[]">
<input type="text" name="amount[]">

<button>Add more</button>
```

Which generate same inputs again:

```
<input type="text" name="category[]">
<input type="text" name="quantity[]">
<input type="text" name="amount[]">
```

A piece of code in Cakephp I have been trying:

```
$data = $this->request->data;
foreach($data['category'] as $index => $value){
 $this->ModelName->save($value);
}
```

Trying to get two rows inserted at once with quantity, category and amount as columns. But it is not inserting and not giving any error.

Is there a way I can achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your model works in cakephp, but you should be able to get a complete grouping of data like:

```
foreach($data['category'] as $index => $value){
    $category = $value
    $quantity = $data['quantity'][$index];
    $amount = $data['amount'][$index];

    // use the above 3 variables however you need to to persist the model
    //$this->ModelName->save($value);
}
```

On a side note, you may want to consider reordering your html inputs to be like:

```
<input type="text" name="item[0][category]">
<input type="text" name="item[0][quantity]">
<input type="text" name="item[0][amount]">
```

And then maintain the next index, incrementing the numeric index of `item` for each additional group

This will allow you to iterate like:

```
foreach($data['item'] as $index => $group){
     //$group['category'];
     //$group['quantity'];
     //$group['amount'];
}
```